# 'Could not configure a C compliler' error while running the command 'python ./waf distclean all' in command prompt

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python script which I need to bundle it into a single exe file using pyinstaller. While running the command 'pyinstaller –-onefile –-windowed myscript.py' through command prompt. I got the error 'Fatal error: PyInstaller does not include a pre-compiled bootloader for your platform' after the line 30389: INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc.

And on googling I found that we need perform certain steps as a pre-requisite  to build bootloader as follows,

Step 1: git clone https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller

Step 2: cd pyinstaller/bootloader

Step 3: python ./waf distclean all

On performing step 3, I got the error like 'Could not configure a C compiler'

Could anyone help me to resolve the same.

Comment: install a C compiler

Comment: What OS are you using? Also, why not install with `pip`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to install c compiler
here is the link
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/cplusplus/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33385666)